# std::chrono::milliseconds .count() returns in microseconds?

Tags: c++11, c++-chrono, milliseconds

I am trying to log milliseconds of time that has elapsed over a period of time.

I have a class like this

```
// class member declarations
class MyClass {

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point   m_start;
    std::chrono::system_clock::duration              m_elapsed;
};
```

I have 2 methods in the class. One is called from main that is `func1CalledFromMainThread`.

```
// Class methods
using namespace std::chrono;
void MyClass::func1CalledFromMainThread() {

    m_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}
```

And another one that is `func2CalledFromADifferentThread` is called from a different thread

```
void MyClass::func2CalledFromADifferentThread() {

    // after some time following line of code runs from a different thread
    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();

    m_elapsed = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - m_start);
    std::cout << "Elapsed time in milliseconds is " << m_elapsed.count()/1000 << std::endl;
}
```

The issue is in the `cout` logging. I see that I have to divide by `1000` to get milliseconds out of `m_elapsed`. Doesn't `count` return the count of `std::chrono::milliseconds` here? Why should I have to divide by `1000` here? Does `count()` return always in `microseconds` or am I doing a mistake?

Comment: Since you are accessing `m_start` from different threads, you should look into `std::mutex`.

Comment: Here is a video `<chrono>` tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M

Comment: @Angew. Yes, I have the mutexes in the actual code which is much more complex than this example. I have just created out an example code to discuss and understand the problem without involving too many details into it which worked I think. Thanks a lot for the useful answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`count` returns the number of ticks of the type on which you invoke it. If you wrote this:

```
duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - m_start).count()
```

it would correctly give you the number of milliseconds. However, you're not storing the result in `std::chrono::milliseconds`, you're storing it in `std::chrono::system_clock::duration` (the type of `m_elapsed`). Therefore, `m_elapsed.count()` returns the number of ticks in `std::chrono::system_clock::duration`'s frequency, which is probably microseconds on your platform.

In other words, you're immediately undoing the cast to `milliseconds` by storing the result in something other than `milliseconds`.

Answer (score 2):

#### You are storing the duration using `system_clock::duration`units and not in `milliseconds`.

The problem in your case is that `std::chrono::system_clock::duration` is not using millisecond as ticks counts.
When executing this line  `m_elapsed = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - m_start);`,
No matter is you convert the time first to `milli` using a `duration_cast`  the count of ticks will always be converted in `system_clock::duration` duration unit which happen to be `microseconds`.

I would simply declare `m_elapsed` as  `std::chrono::duration<long, std::milli>` and it should work as expected.

- Have a look at the [doc page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast) for more info

Answer (score 0):

I faced with similar problem and I resolved it by simple change 
from:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::duration              m_elapsed;
```

to:

```
auto m_elapsed;
```